# c++ Japanese characters command line output

Tags: c++

I am having problems to print Japanese characters on my command line (osx) with c++.

I would be happy to see any character printed correctly on my command line, but I dont get what my problem is. Nothing is printed, not even a wrong character nor any error occurs. My characters are just swallowed. What am I doing wrong here?

```
 #include <string>
#include <clocale>
#include<iostream>

int main(int argc, char** args){

    std::setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
    wchar_t c=L'あ';
    std::wcout<<c;

    std::wstring s = L"あ";
    std::wcout<<s;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't need the line:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

That's used for things like date and time formats.

Instead, imbue the output stream with a properly initialized `locale` object.

```
std::wcout.imbue(std::locale("ja_jp.utf-8"));
```